# SWRevealViewController with TabBarController and NavigationController - Swift 3

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, segue, swrevealviewcontroller

I want all my app pages to have a side-menu button on the navigation bar which opens the same side menu(done through `SWRevealViewController`)

Here is my storyboard structure :

[image]

My initial view controller is `SWRevealViewController`. The navigation controller is connected to it by the sw_front set segue and sw_rear set segue is the side menu view controller(on the top right).

Now the problem is that all the view controllers at the bottom require the same side menu to be opened. I have given reveal push segue from side menu view controller to tab bar controller for the same.

Also I have written the following code in the view controller class of the bottom left. the left bar button item's outlet is named `menuButton`

```
if self.revealViewController() != nil {
        menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
        menuButton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
    }
```

I cannot understand what is wrong.

Note : There might be a problem as the main navigation controller's root view controller and the tab bar are connected through code instead of segue (as segue was giving a problem in navigation bar of sub tab's).

The code used for the same is :

```
let mainST = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
    let VC = mainST.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "idTabBar") as! TabBarController
    VC.index = tappedImageTag
    present(VC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Please help. I am using xcode 8 and swift 3.

EDIT : I tried this in the sideMenuViewController(shown on the top right of storyboard image)

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "idTabBar") as! TabBarController
    vc.index = 0
    let rvc:SWRevealViewController = self.revealViewController() as SWRevealViewController
    rvc.pushFrontViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

When I go from home page's side menu through this code to any other page then the side menu button works on that page as well.
But if I go directly to those pages my side menu doesn't appear.

It's a really silly mistake that I'm doing but please help me figure it out.